# LTSpice: why does my .MEAS 3dB calculation disagree with the cursors on the plot?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I'm exploring the `.MEAS` command with the following simple BJT Class-AB amplifier:

[image: straightforward BJT Class-AB amplifier]

And am getting the following results from my `.MEAS` commands in the error log:

```
vout_max: MAX(mag(v(vout)))=(27.4778dB,0°) FROM 10 TO 1e+010
vout_3db: vout_max/sqrt(2)=(24.4675dB,0°)
f_3db: freq=(142.323dB,0°) at 1.30662e+007
```

The results for `vout_max` and `vout_3db` seem correct, they agree with the plot to at least 2 decimal places.

I'm very puzzled by the results for `f_3db` however. It appears to call `V(vout)` crossing the -3dB point at 13.06MHz, where the plot (screenshot below) has it at 19.41MHz.

[image: screenshot of the plot window showing cursors measuring the -3dB point at 19.405 megahertz]

- Why are these numbers so different?
- Have I written these `.MEAS` commands wrong?

I expected these to agree to at least several decimal places given they're both calculated from the same simulation run.

Comment: None of your results match the schematic. This is not a Class AB amplifier, rather it is a unity voltage gain common collector(aka emitter follower) bipolar amplifier with an overall current gain  < 2 due to 1000/500 ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AC analysis produces complex numbers with 'real' and 'imaginary' parts that carry the magnitude and phase information in a vector. The function `MAG()` is used to extract the magnitude.

You have done this for `vout_max`, but not for `V(vout)`, so the comparison will give unexpected results. Change `V(vout)` to `MAG(V(vout))` in the last `.MEAS` command and it should find the correct frequency.